# Is it possible to print a subscript number in cmd using Java?

Tags: java, cmd

I was thinking if there's a way to print subscript numbers (0-9) in cmd. The cmd doesn't seem to recognize these types of characters that's why it prints a "?" instead. I have to pass this program to our teacher so changing my system font won't actually work.

```
String val = "\u2082"; //unicode value of subscript-two
System.out.print(val);
```

The reason why I want to achieve this is because I created a Number System Conversion program (console) and decided to include their subscript (base numbers) so that it'd be much easier to recognize what numbers are they (binary, decimal, octal, hexadecimal).

Comment: [Change your font](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/quick-tip-add-fonts-to-the-command-prompt/#targetText=Because%20Raster%20Fonts%20are%20no,fonts%20that%20come%20with%20Windows.).

Comment: Is there another way? My java program will be submitted to our teacher so I can't do that. :(

Comment: Sorry. You'd have to change your teacher's font. Have you ever seen it work on the command line with any other program?

Comment: Yes, and it also prints "?" instead of the unicode subscript number that I want to display.

Comment: Oh sorry... The subscript number is printed whenever I run the program online or use a code editor like VS Code.

Comment: But in other computer's cmd, it just prints "?"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Unicode subscript and superscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts).

```
String water = "H\u2082O"; // H₂O
```

In case of problem with Unicode, try to use UTF-8

```
Charset utf8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
String water = new String("H\u2082O".getBytes(utf8));
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Thank you, but in my case, I am also using that unicode value but it just prints "?" in my cmd instead.

Comment: I updated the previous answer to include the "?" problem.