# How to print powers in Java?

Tags: java

Is there a way to print powers in java ? I am not talking about Math.pow(a, b) . In the terminal window, is it possible to print powers such that `b` is as a superscript ?

I tried using the `System.out.println(a^b) ;` and it is only possible to write it as `a^b` where `b` is not a superscript.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts. You might want to check other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58549186/is-it-possible-to-print-a-subscript-number-in-cmd-using-java or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058768/superscript-in-java-string

Comment: As far as I know it's not possible to change the superscript of a char in the terminal, however, if your terminal supports it, you could try using superscript unicode characters
https://rupertshepherd.info/resource_pages/superscript-letters-in-unicode

Comment: Probably not, or only for characters that are included in the terminal's  supported character set. Maybe you get a superscript 2 or 3, and that's it. Keep in mind, it's just a terminal, not a browser or typesetting environment.

Comment: only 2 or 3 using escape sequence ? Can't we use any package classes for printing any power in superscript ?

Comment: You have to repeat the proper unicode for each digit. You could easily generate a static map and build the the exponent sequence for the desired number.  That map could be kept in a library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  You can do it like this. This is the unicode version for superscript.  There are other codes that let you do letters and other digits.  This is just an example.  Here is a [link](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/search?q=superscript#characters) for the digits and some special characters.  I do not know how stable this link is.

```
System.out.println("km\u00B2");
System.out.println("2\u00B3");
```

prints

```
km²
2³
```

If the target output device supports it, you can also use html.

```
System.out.println("km<sup>2</sup>")
System.out.println("2<sup>3</sup>")
```

**Update**

I have included some code to facilitate multi-digit exponents.

- first, create an array of unicode exponents from 0 to 9 inclusive.

```
String[] uniDigits = new String[10];        
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    uniDigits[i] = switch(i) {
        case 2,3->Character.toString(0xB0+i);
        case 1 -> Character.toString(0xB9);        
        case 0,4,5,6,7,8,9->Character.toString(0x2070+i);
        default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException();       
        };
}
```

Then I created a `BiFunction`  which takes the exponent and the digit array as arguments and returns the exponent.

```
BiFunction<Integer, String[], String> exponent = (exp, unis)-> {
    int offset = 0;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (exp < 0) {
        offset = 1;
        exp = -exp;
        sb.append(Character.toString(0x207B)); // minus sign
    }
    int digits = exp == 0 ? 1 : (int)Math.log10(exp)+1;
    while(digits-- > 0) {
        sb.insert(offset, unis[exp%10]);
        exp/=10;
    }
    return sb.toString();
};
    
System.out.println("10%s".formatted(exponent.apply(213,uniDigits)));
System.out.println("15%s".formatted(exponent.apply(-38,uniDigits)));
```

prints

```
10²¹³
15⁻³⁸
```

Instead of using the `BiFunction` directly, you can also return a `Function` that takes a single argument of exponent and calls the BiFunction with the exponent and the digit array.

```
Function<Integer, String> expf = exp-> exponent.apply(exp,uniDigits);
```

It does the same thing, just saves some typing if you have to sprinkle them around in your code.

Comment: I'm using BlueJ, so HTML won't work here. The 1st escape sequence works. But it is only for squares and cubes... I am writing a binomial theorem program where I wanna print any **powers** .  How can I do it ?

Comment: Did you look at the link? All the other digits are there...

Comment: wait checking...

Comment: no how can we use this to print multiple digit powers ?

Comment: It is going to be a problem because the superscript to be printed has to be divided into its constituent digits if multiple escape sequences is the only option available.

Comment: @SuperCoder You have to repeat the proper unicode for each digit. You could easily generate a static map and build the the exponent sequence for the desired number. That map could be kept in a library.   Perhaps some Apache or other 3rd party library library has a more versatile mechanism.